# problem reversing feed url

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am using the development version. I get the error below when I try to reverse lookup my feed's URL.

Can anyone help please?

thanks
konstantin

in my urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^f/blog/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.Feed', BlogFeed(), name='blog-feed'),
...
```

in my template:

```
...
{% url blog-feed %}
...
```

the error:

```
...
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'BlogFeed' object has no attribute 'keys'
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your BlogFeed class is the class based view, I don't think you need the 'django.contrib.syndication.views.Feed' part... your BlogFeed should be a subclass of that. ([django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/syndication/))

```
url(r'^f/blog/$', BlogFeed(), name="blog-feed"),
```

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url) should be a dictionary. I'm not sure why you've got a class.

Maybe what you are trying to do is,

```
url(r'^f/blog/$', 'django.contrib.syndication.views.Feed', {'name_of_view_arg':BlogFeed()}, name="blog-feed"),
```

Comment: this was the case before, now in 1.3+ it is supposed to be this way.

Comment: I still see `kwargs` as the third parameter in the development version  documentation (linked to in my post). I've edited my answer (retained the `name` argument, but kept the third argument as a dictionary, not a `BlogFeed` object).